# Coordinates must be finite numbers error on map.getBounds()

Tags: leaflet

I get the following error when trying to get a getBounds for my map.

```
*proj4-src.js:1849 Uncaught TypeError: coordinates must be finite numbers
    at checkCoord (proj4-src.js:1849)
    at checkSanity (proj4-src.js:1841)
    at transform (proj4-src.js:1865)
    at transformer (proj4-src.js:1944)
    at Object.forward (proj4-src.js:2010)
    at NewClass.project (proj4leaflet.js:40)
    at vers copy.html:80*
```

I'm using a 28992 projection.

```
  var RD = new L.Proj.CRS(
        'EPSG:28992',
        '+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857330322398,0.350732676542563,-1.8703473836068,4.0812 +no_defs', {
        origin: [-285401.92, 22598.08],
        resolutions: [3440.640, 1720.320, 860.160, 430.080, 215.040, 107.520, 53.760, 26.880, 13.440, 6.720, 3.360, 1.680, 0.840, 0.420, 0.210, 0.105],
        bounds: L.bounds([-285401.92, 22598.08], [595401.920, 903401.920])


var wgs84 = map.getBounds().getEast();
console.log(wgs84);
RdNew= RD.projection.project(wgs84);
console.log(RdNew);
```

The console log for wgs84 gives the correct coordinate.
The console log for RdNew gives the error listed above

Comment: If you look at the docs, you'll see that projection `.project` method requires `L.latLng` input parameter, but bounds `.getEast()` method returns just single number which is east longitude of the bounds. You have to use either `.getSouthEast()` or `.getNorthEast` method to get `L.latLng`  coordinate.